# Explaining batch normalization in terms of Gaussian processes

Tags: neural-networks, gaussian-process, batch-normalization

In [this video](https://youtu.be/NHTGY8VCinY?t=37m31s) on Deep Gaussian Processes, Neil Lawrence (at 37:30) mentions that thinking of the layers of a neural network in terms of basis functions from Gaussian processes can be viewed as a motivation/explanation for Ioffe/Szegedy's [batch normalization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf). Can someone explain this comment to me? I'm not understanding what he means.